# ReactJS remove root component on certain page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am looking for a solution that will remove a `<header/>` and `<footer/>` component from my `signup.js` and `signin.js` pages.

Currently, my root `index.js` file is shown as

```
class Template extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
        <main>
          <Header/>
          {children()}
          <Footer/>
        </main>
    )
}}
Template.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func
}
export default Template
```

Which is the main layout for all my page, posts, products, etc. Yet without creating another layout, I would like to conditionally remove the `<header/>` and `<footer/>` components from being a part of pages `signup.js` and `signin.js`

As suggested by GatsbyJS I have tried - of which is removing the components from all pages.

```
if (this.props.location.pathname !== "/signup/") {
   return (
      <main>
         {children()}
      </main>
    )
} else {
    return this (
      <main>
         <Header/>
         {children()}
         <Footer/>
      </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: why not create a new template for signin/signup?

Comment: Haha... haven't got that far in my React/Gatsby learning journey. Does sound like a better idea though.

Comment: Is there performance reasons why I would want to do that opposed to adding conditions?

Comment: I think that performance is not an issue with adding conditions. But the main difference is about maintainability.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing about making different layouts

Comment: By the way, I saw an issue in your code. In your `else` it says `return this(` which should be removed.

Comment: Thank you @muZk I have now cloned the `index.js` layout and mapped a new one to my on-boarding pages. It works a treat and agreed I much prefer this method for maintainability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a different template for your signin and signup components, but if you don't do that:

You have a typo in your code, in your `else` you are returning `this(...)` it should return `(...)`. This way:

```
if (this.props.location.pathname !== "/signup/") {
   return (
      <main>
         {children()}
      </main>
    )
} else {
    return (
      <main>
         <Header/>
         {children()}
         <Footer/>
      </main>
    )
}
```

Also, perhaps your `if` condition is inverted... because in `/signup/` you don't want `Header` and `Footer`:

```
if (this.props.location.pathname === "/signup/" || this.props.location.pathname === "/signin/") {
   return (
      <main>
         {children()}
      </main>
    )
} else {
    return (
      <main>
         <Header/>
         {children()}
         <Footer/>
      </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: Cheers muZk. Agreed above with the comment about a new layout but for the sake of my question I tried your code and it works as intended.

Comment: What if we want to remove the main component?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to duplicate code...

```
const isSignIn = ["/signup/", "/signin/"].indexOf( this.props.location.pathname) !== 0;

return (
  <main>
     { !isSignIn && (<Header/>) }
     {children()}
     { !isSignIn && (<Footer/>) }
  </main>
)
```